# Find the value of modulus z

Tags: complex-numbers

If the area of the triangle formed by the points $z$, $z+iz$,$i z$ on the complex plane is $18$ then the value of $|z|$ is ?

Comment: You told us only two points. For are triangle we need three points !

Comment: And the third point is?

Comment: Sorry third point is 'iz'

Answer (score 1):

This is halve of a square with side length $|z|,$ i.e. $\frac{1}{2}|z|^2 = 18$,
so $|z| = ???$

Comment: Correct answer but how did you do??

Comment: As already said, your triangle is halve of the square given by $0,z,zi,z+zi.$
Remember that multiplication by $i$ is a rotation with $90°.$

Comment: Thanks for your help